# ASP.NET Web API Routing Query Parameters

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a StudentsController and I currently have the following working:

```
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students   <-- returns list of students
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students/5 <-- returns student with Id = 5
```

I have a requirement to return all students in the class of 2013, but the below of course will not work:

```
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students/2013 <-- won't work, because it would look for the student with Id = 2013
```

I could do this:

```
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students?gradclass=2013
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to do it that might make sense without a query string, such as:

```
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students/gradclasses/2013
```

The above sort of makes sense, but this does not quite make sense:

```
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students/gradclasses <-- this sort of makes no sense
```

Also, using routing what would be the approach to set up the proper solution once we figure it out?

Is this worthwhile? What's the best practice? I'm struggling to find best practices on REST and GET Query parameters.

Comment: Student and Class should be different resources...so the uri for getting all students of a class should be like `/class/{year}/students` and probably pointing to a classes controller...if you do not like to have a different controller, you could have the action (to get all students of a class) in the students controller and decorate it with attribute routing...

Comment: This makes sense.  But what about a case where I want to show all students who have job offers? And then another case where I want to show students who don't have job offers?  Also what would a GET look like on just the /class straight up?

Answer (score 0):

I'd treat "students in the class of 2013" as a view. And then compose api as /type/view/params.
So:
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students/byclass/2013
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students/withJobOffer
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students/repeaters/2012

Indeed views can overlap. That's more complex. Then you have to deal with query string:
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/students?class=2013&withJobOffer=true&repeaters=2012

Answer (score 0):

As REST is about thinking through resources that you can navigate through, even without knowing the structure in advance, I'd add on your working sample of getting all students and a single student by treating the gradclasses as another type of resource, like this:

```
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/gradclasses/ => Return all grad classes
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/gradclasses/2013/ => Return a grad class of 2013 with it's info
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/gradclasses/2013/students/ => Return the students of grad class 2013
```

This way you'll have a nice relation and an easily explorable content.

Going even further, should you want to abstract away the fact that students have a globally unique ID to increase persistence ignorance, you could implement the getting of a student only as this:

```
http://mycompany.com/api/v1/gradclasses/2013/students/5 => Return the student 5 of grad class 2013
```